# Find groups of connected nodes in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with label `A`. Some of them are connected with the relationship `TEST` (see Figure A).

I want to `MATCH` the groups of connected nodes, create a new node `B` for each group and create a relationship from each member of the group to the new node `B` (see Figure B). I know that the groups are small, never more then 3 steps of `TEST` relationships.

How can I `MATCH` the `A` nodes and return connected groups? Is there a graph algorithm implemented in APOC?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, maybe it's still helpful for someone:

There are several algorithms for community detection in the graph algorithm package ()https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/. In this case, we look for **connected components**: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/connected-components/

The algorithm can find connected components and store an ID for the component on the nodes:

```
CALL algo.unionFind('A', 'TEST', {write:true, partitionProperty:"partition"})
YIELD nodes, setCount, loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis;
```

With this new property it's simple to `MATCH` all nodes belonging to a particular group:

```
MATCH (a:A)
WITH a.partition AS p, a
RETURN p, count(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`algo.unionFind` seems to be deprecated. The replacement is:

```
CALL gds.wcc.write('A', {nodeLabels: 'TEST', writeProperty: 'partition' });
```

Here is the syntax from the docs

```
CALL gds.wcc.write(
  graphName: String,
  configuration: Map
)
YIELD
  componentCount: Integer,
  nodePropertiesWritten: Integer,
  preProcessingMillis: Integer,
  computeMillis: Integer,
  writeMillis: Integer,
  postProcessingMillis: Integer,
  componentDistribution: Map,
  configuration: Map
```

See https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/wcc/ for details